# Leaflet Map in R as a Globe

Tags: r, leaflet

Hi I have a question about Leaflet library in R. Map in Leaflet is as very long horizontal paper with repeated view of world. The problem is, that when I mark something near Australia, It have marked it only in one place although we can see on map (screen below) Australia 3 times. It is possible to make this map repeated and when I will mark for example Poland on map, Poland will be marked everywhere it appears?

Code Below (example from library webpage):

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(data=quakes, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), clusterId = "quakesCluster") %>%
  addEasyButton(
    easyButton(
      states = list(
        easyButtonState(
          stateName="unfrozen-markers",
          icon="ion-toggle",
          title="Freeze Clusters",
          onClick = JS("
            function(btn, map) {
            var clusterManager =
            map.layerManager.getLayer('cluster', 'quakesCluster');
            clusterManager.freezeAtZoom();
            btn.state('frozen-markers');
            }")
        ),
        easyButtonState(
          stateName="frozen-markers",
          icon="ion-toggle-filled",
          title="UnFreeze Clusters",
          onClick = JS("
            function(btn, map) {
            var clusterManager =
            map.layerManager.getLayer('cluster', 'quakesCluster');
            clusterManager.unfreeze();
            btn.state('unfrozen-markers');
            }")
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag `shiny`?

Comment: because I use it in my shiny app. I will remove it

Answer (score 0):

This exists, but I can't help with how to integrate it with R.

https://www.maptiler.com/news/2014/07/webgl-earth-2-leaflet-compatible/